# Having some problem with discord bot which i am coding in replit

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I cant start my discord bot in replti.com
Is their any fault in my code?

```
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")
    print(client.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send(message.content[::-1])

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Have you imported discord?

Comment: Yes i imported discord module

Comment: `import discord` is not appearing in your code. So if you have imported it, please make the changes in your question as well for the benefit of others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using is not good.
Rather do this `from discord.ext import commands`

and then insert commands as such:

```py
@client.commands()
async def hello("")
```

Comment: Ok i will try this now